# best practice for efficient xpath selectors

Tags: xslt, xpath

Are there some general tips or best practices on how to create more efficient xpath selectors in xslt?

For example, say you have a DocBook XML document that only contains first-level sections, like this:

```
<chapter>
  <section><info><title>my first section</title></info> ... </section>
  <section userlevel="expert"><info><title>my second section</title></info> ... </section>
  <section><info><title>my third section</title></info> ... </section>
</chapter>
```

I *think* that in nearly all cases a selector like `//d:section`(1) is worse that one like `/d:chapter/d:section`(2). Can I generalize that and say that the more selective the selector the faster it will be?

For another example: If you want the second section element, you could pull it from a sub-tree of all sections or select it directly with `//d:section[@userlevel]`.  This selector uses the attribute which is more selective but would it be faster?

Rules of thumb of what to do (or to avoid) when using XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to look at a particular XSLT or XPath or XQuery processor or even at a particular processor and a particular tree model and then run tests. For instance `//foo` so so common that it might be optimized in an implementation.

When I run Saxon 9.5 Java HE with the XQuery `//section` ten times on your input sample I get "Average execution time: 1.007739ms" while with `/chapter/section` I get "Average execution time: 1.443799ms".

Comment: Interesting. Really an optimization or probably the file system cache? I would usually rewrite `//section` to `/chapter/section`, but in some cases it's probably better the other way around. For instance if the path selects most nodes in the document and the nodes of for instance a database are clustered in preorder. In a B+-clustered index it's then simply following the datapage pointers and filter some nodes from the result.

Comment: I guess it all depends on the document in question. I was hoping for a simple list of things to look out for, but xpath is not open to that kind of (over) simplification.

Comment: If you want a list of things to look out for with XSLT 2.0 then check the article "The ten most common XSLT programming mistakes" on http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2010/06/.